# AdMob Automatically Requesting Another Interstitial Ad

Tags: ios, admob

I'm seeing some very strange behavior with AdMob interstitials on iOS.

After closing an interstitial, AdMob automatically requests another interstitial without me creating a new `GADInterstitial` or calling `loadRequest`.

I can see this because I use `GADCustomEventInterstitals`, and I log when they're being used.

The next time I allocate a `GADInterstitial` and call `loadRequest`, AdMob loads the ad immediately without running through the ad mediation stack.  The ad it loads is the one that was received when AdMob requested an ad without me asking for it.

It's as if AdMob is trying to automatically cache the next ad as soon as the previous ad has finished.  I don't particularly want this behavior, and if I did, I could implement it myself.

In testing different versions of the Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, I noticed that this behavior doesn't occur in version 7.6.  But it does happen in version 7.16, 7.19, and 7.26.

Has anyone else noticed this sort of thing?  Is there a way to turn it off or prevent it from happening?

Comment: Remove the loop from the code.

Comment: There's no loop in my code.  The problem is with the AdMob library.  I gave the AdMob developers a sample that reproduces the problem and they say they're working on it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/8xDRxx3xKtE/jqHR7PEzBwAJ

Comment: I am also following that thread now. :) Hope they will resolve the issue soon. Cheers.

Comment: Good news.  The AdMob team reached out to me to say that they think they fixed the issue.  And indeed, when I tested, the problem no longer happened.  I didn't have to update the sdk either.